# How to move 1000 files to RDD's?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new in Apache Spark and need help.

I have python script with reading 6 tdms files (TDMS() function) and building graph for numerical data of each of them (GRAPH() function). I do it with for loop.
But I want to load 1000 such files and to run this script in parallels for each one. So I want to create RDD's with this files and apply my function to each file?

How can I do it? 
Can I define number of nodes in Spark?

Comment: I am not sure what the tdms files are, but majority of the functions in spark can take a directory as an input file (which is "sum" of all files in this directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making Python list that includes all the files you need to read, and run those in for loop to read data from file, create RDD, run graph function, and I guess save it?

Or make the file list as RDD, and run those with map, lambda(for graph), for each.

If you are only care about parallel run, you can just keep loading data and make one big RDD, and call sc.parallelize. You can either decide Spark to do it, or you can even specify the number you want to use by calling sc.parallelize(data, ).